# How can the baker and accuser logging level be reduced?

Tags: logging

I've set my node's log level to 'warn' which reduced quite a bit of noise.

`.tezos-node/config.json`

```
{
        "log": {
                "level": "warn"
        }
}
```

But the baker and accuser are still too noisy and I'd like to eliminated the following informational messages.

```
May  9 06:36:09 odroid tezos-baker-003-PsddFKi3[3832]: May  9 06:36:09 - client.baking: No slot found at level 429711 (max_priority = 64)
May  9 06:37:02 odroid tezos-accuser-003-PsddFKi3[3740]: May  9 06:37:02 - client.denunciation: Block BM8DoWnzngdk registered
```

I suppose I could redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null` but I'd still like to have warnings and errors appear in my syslog.